# knockout.js. Disable property multi conditions binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have custom binding and a use this code to observe disable property of the element.
init function:

```
var updateAttributes = function () {
   disable = allBindingsAccessor().disable
   var isDisabled = disable === true || (disable != undefined && ko.isObservable(disable) && disable());
   $(element).prop('disabled', isLoading || !hasOptions || hasOneOption || !!isDisabled);
}

if (allBindingsAccessor().disable != undefined && ko.isObservable(allBindingsAccessor().disable)) {
     allBindingsAccessor().disable.subscribe(function () {
           updateAttributes();
           $(element).selectpicker('refresh');
     });
}
```

But now i have a problem if disable property depends on multi conditions such as

```
disable: cond1() || cond2()
```

Maybe somebody know better way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case i am using:

```
disable: ko.pureComputed(function() { return cond1() || cond2(); })
```